# Device driver development

Tags: objective-c, macos, network-programming, device-driver

Whether Objective C is used for any Device driver developments?
now I am working as a ios developer.Is it possible to work in any other domains with this experience

Comment: I'm at a loss as to what the last sentence means. Do you mean it as a question? Or as the reason you are working as an iOS developer.

Comment: its a question....i am having experience in c++ and c...but i got a new job as ios developer ....so now am studying Objective C..i thinking about my future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you’ve tagged your question as [mac](/questions/tagged/mac), I’m assuming you mean device drivers for Mac OS X. In that case, they’re developed in C++ and use I/O Kit. More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingDeviceDriver/Introduction/Intro.html) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 2):

I comes from kernel level programming and now working on iphone and android developement..And I will tell you from my experience that going opposite (application programming to system level.) is like climbing everest..There is nothing to compare between two..

99 percent of system level coding happens in C, and for kernel programming purest form of C is used..Debugging is very difficult there, a segmentation fault in application programming is a kernel panic (only solution to it is reboot) in kernel programming..It is not about having to reboot, but on a reboot we loss entire information (crash information about our failed project)so that it is very difficult to debug..Surely kernel programming and device driver development is more challenging..

Comment: i know both C and C++.... and now am studying Objective C .. i am a beginner in Objective C and Xcode

Comment: "Surely kernel programming and device driver development is more challenging". It may be more challenging but it is not something which requires creativity that you need at application development level. The challenge in DD development is because we have these monolithic kernel based operating system which were designed in older days of computing and during DD development you will be fighting against the kernel API etc more than you own driver logic

Comment: I agree with you there..you are always fighting against the kernel itself..And it will be very difficult for someone who worked in the application level to comprehend..There is more chance for you to get stuck, more chance to bang your head..Also most importantly, to get help when you are stuck is even more difficult..

Answer (score 1):

Device driver development is very specific domain. If you have been a application developer and even though you know a programming language which support driver development it would not be just an easy switch to driver development as it will be all together different concepts, APIs etc that you need to learn and get a good hold of because when a driver (kernel mode) crashes it brings down the whole system. I don't think Objective-C is used for driver development. This area is for C or in some cases C++. I have done some driver development and felt application development is much more fun then driver development as in driver development you would be writing code that talk to hardware and thats it, just pass data back and froth between hardware and OS, where as in application development you can do a whole lot of amazing things, your imagination is the only limit :)

Comment: i know both C and C++.... and now am studying Objective C .. i am a beginner in Objective C and Xcode and i iphone development